# After taking selected area screenshot on 20.04 I can not click anything "on desktop", wrong cursor state ensues

Tags: mouse, screenshot

So to reproduce, I do ctrl-shift-4 (remapped the select screen shot command due to some other conflict) and select an area on chrome. Notably I am doing this while first enabling some dropdown in chrome that might be interfering with the onclick.

After I select an area, I can still use and click into open apps but I can not click apps in the desktops or drawers. I can navigate using the keyboard, but not using the mouse *clicks* mouse movement still works. Is there something I might pkill to get out of this without rebooting?